# I can't boot my netbook after sparkylinux installation

Tags: boot, bios, netbook, acer-aspire-one

Big problem for me, everything was ok installing Sparky Linux from a usb pendrive, but at the end of installation I selected the box reboot now then confirm it.

The netbook was shutting down BUT I PRESSED the key F2 several times to change the boot order devices in BIOS (during the shutdown process).

Now I can't boot the netbook nor access the BIOS, when I power on I got immediately a black screen, noway to access the BIOS, do I have to disassembly the netbook to take the CMOS battery out then put it again??

I don't know what to do. Appreciate some help.

netbook  : Acer Aspire One zg5 (I know this is old netbook), I upgraded HDD for a SSD sandisk 128GB

I tried Linux pendrive boot-recovery, no success.

Unplug from charger then holding down power button 20/30 seconds then power on again, no success.(netbook have NO battery). appreciate some help.

Comment: Try resetting the BIOS via the CMOS battery, if there is one. Normally such a problem is not connected to the installed OS, but rather to some hardware glitch.

Comment: Noway, now I'll remove the SSD then plug in via usb to another  laptop and try to access the drive, your suggestion didn't work, thanks

Comment: I think the problem occurred after a corrupted OS installation .

Comment: The problem you are describing sounds more like a corrupted BIOS. It would be strange if the Linux installation tried to update the BIOS, but I don't know Sparky Linux. You could try to reset the BIOS (not CMOS), just that this usually requires a Windows or DOS environment.